# Как поставить beautifier на Qt Creator для автоформатирования кода

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

хочу поставить плагин для автоформатирования кода на `C++`, но не могу найти где скачать и как поставить `source` для `beautifier` и `clang format` сразу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*кто знает как это сделать буду очень рад помощи!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Открываете Help->About Plugins и ищите эти два плагина (там есть поле ввода для быстрого поиска) и ставите галочки напротив них. И перезапускаете редактор (он сам предложит это). Все, готово.

Теперь можно пойти в Tools->Options->Beautifier и там настроить по вкусу.

И теперь с меню Tools->Beautifier->Clang format можно форматировать все, что нужно.

Comment: он сам не хочет скачивать и предлагает чтобы я указал пути на эти плагины, добавил картинку в вопрос

Comment: нужно просто галочки проставить и нажать close/закрыть. Не нужно нажимать "Install".

Comment: Нет необходимости включать плагин ClangFormat, одного плагина Beautifier хватает.

Comment: Beautifier умеет работать с другими форматерами. тут по пожеланиям.

Comment: Я про то, чтобы использовать clang-format в плагине Beautifier, не нужно включать плагин ClangFormat.

Comment: тут все чуточку сложнее, чем кажется. Beautifier используется для форматирования кода, когда хочет автор кода. И он может использовать clang-format для этого. А вот плагин ClangFormat  используется для того, что бы форматировать "на ходу" - в процессе написания кода, что бы он выравнивался красиво (https://www.qt.io/blog/2019/04/17/clangformat-plugin-qt-creator-4-9)